# unable to display count of tickets with pivot table by week of year

Tags: sql, pivot-table, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My requirement is write script that will return data set showing count of tickets in Q3 of 2021. The result set must be a pivot table by account, account name, and week of year.

so the columns should be something like (account id, account name, 07/04, 07/11,07,18, etc.)

I can only produce results with pivot table if I list every day in pivot table, but that is not desired outcome. Please help. Thank you

here is what I have so far that produces pivot table for each day:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT
            A.ACCOUNTID AS "Account ID",
            A.NAME AS "Account Name",
            CASE WHEN MONTH(C."CREATED DATE") <= 9 AND DAY(C."CREATED 
DATE") <=9 THEN
                    CONCAT('0',MONTH (C."CREATED DATE") ,'/0', 
DAY(C."CREATED DATE"))
                WHEN MONTH(C."CREATED DATE") <= 9 AND DAY(C."CREATED 
DATE") > 9 THEN
                    CONCAT('0',month (C."CREATED DATE") ,'/', 
DAY(C."CREATED DATE"))
                 WHEN MONTH(C."CREATED DATE") > 9 AND DAY(C."CREATED 
DATE") <= 9 THEN
                    CONCAT(MONTH (C."CREATED DATE") ,'/0', 
DAY(C."CREATED DATE"))
                 ELSE
                    CONCAT(month (C."CREATED DATE") ,'/', 
DAY(C."CREATED DATE"))
                 END
                    AS WEEK,
        COUNT(DISTINCT C.CASEID)AS TicketCount
        FROM PROD_DB_SOURCE.SALESFORCE.ACCOUNT A
        LEFT JOIN PROD_DB_SOURCE.SALESFORCE."CASE" C
        ON A.ACCOUNTID = C.ACCOUNTID
        LEFT JOIN PROD_DB_BUSINESS.SUPPORT.HEADCOUNT HC
            ON C.OWNERID = HC.CRMUSERID
        WHERE HC.LEVEL = 'Analyst'
        AND (C."CREATED DATE") != (C."CLOSED DATE")
        AND (c."CREATED DATE" BETWEEN '2021-07-01' AND '2021-09-30' )
        GROUP BY A.ACCOUNTID,C.CASEID,C."CREATED DATE",A.NAME,
        CASE WHEN MONTH(C."CREATED DATE") <= 9 AND DAY(C."CREATED 
   DATE") <=9 THEN
                    CONCAT('0',MONTH (C."CREATED DATE") ,'/0', 
 DAY(C."CREATED DATE"))
                WHEN MONTH(C."CREATED DATE") <= 9 AND DAY(C."CREATED 
 DATE") > 9 THEN
                    CONCAT('0',month (C."CREATED DATE") ,'/', 
 DAY(C."CREATED DATE"))
                 WHEN MONTH(C."CREATED DATE") > 9 AND DAY(C."CREATED 
 DATE") <= 9 THEN
                    CONCAT(MONTH (C."CREATED DATE") ,'/0', 
 DAY(C."CREATED DATE"))
                 ELSE
                    CONCAT(month (C."CREATED DATE") ,'/',  
 DAY(C."CREATED DATE"))
                 END
        ORDER BY A.NAME ASC
              ) A
 PIVOT
        (COUNT(TicketCount)
            FOR WEEK
        IN
        ('07/01',
        '07/02',
        '07/03',
        '07/04',
        '07/05',
        '07/06',
        '07/07',
        '07/08',
        '07/09',
        '07/10',
        '07/11',
        '07/12',
        '07/13',
        '07/14',
        '07/15',
        '07/16',
        '07/17',
        '07/18',
        '07/19',
        '07/20',
        '07/21',
        '07/22',
        '07/23',
        '07/24',
        '07/25',
        '07/26',
        '07/27',
        '07/28',
        '07/29',
        '07/30',
        '07/31',
        '08/01',
        '08/02',
        '08/03',
        '08/04',
        '08/05',
        '08/06',
        '08/07',
        '08/08',
        '08/09',
        '08/10',
        '08/11',
        '08/12',
        '08/13',
        '08/14',
        '08/15',
        '08/16',
        '08/17',
        '08/18',
        '08/19',
        '08/20',
        '08/21',
        '08/22',
        '08/23',
        '08/24',
        '08/25',
        '08/26',
        '08/27',
        '08/28',
        '08/29',
        '08/30',
        '08/31',
        '09/01',
        '09/02',
        '09/03',
        '09/04',
        '09/05',
        '09/06',
        '09/07',
        '09/08',
        '09/09',
        '09/10',
        '09/11',
        '09/12',
        '09/13',
        '09/14',
        '09/15',
        '09/16',
        '09/17',
        '09/18',
        '09/19',
        '09/20',
        '09/21',
        '09/22',
        '09/23',
        '09/24',
        '09/25',
        '09/26',
        '09/27',
        '09/28',
        '09/29',
        '09/30')
        )
            AS PIV
```

What I am trying to produce is the sum of tickets created on each week of year in Q3 for that week, so the week of 7/11/21 would include the sum of tickets from 7/11, 7/12, 7/13, 7/14, 7/15, 7/16, 7/17

Comment: Could you add the query you have tried?

Comment: Natively, SQL doesn't support dynamic column names. It breaks a whole raft of deliberate design principles for the language and the DBMS implementations. Your choices are to use SQL's ***intended*** data structure *(normalised; that is each date as a row, not a column)* and do the pivoting in your reporting layer, or to use what is called 'Dynamic-SQL'. The latter is code that reads the database for dates that exist in the data, uses that result to write the SQL you dislike, and runs that new SQL as a new query. Exactly what syntax is needed for the latter depends on Which DBMS you are using.

Comment: update to requirement with current code added to my original post. thank you

Comment: What kind of database and version? *(I thought salesforce runs typically on an Oracle, but those concats with 3 parameters makes me doubt that's the case here)*. And btw, people on SO normally don't have access to such tables. That's why SO advices to create a [minimal and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help them to help you.

Comment: I'm using snowflake DW

Comment: BTW, thank you for reminding me to create reproducible example I'm still very new to posting questions.

Answer (score 0):

Just a test to demonstrate that the source query for the pivot can be simplified.
Repeating that long `CASE WHEN` in the GROUP BY just makes it bloated.

Note, the test works on Postgresql.
But Postgresql doesn't have such PIVOT syntax.
And snowflake sql might need different date functions.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE "CASE" (
> ACCOUNTID INT, 
> NAME VARCHAR(30),
> "CREATED DATE" DATE, 
> CASEID INT
> )
>
> INSERT INTO "CASE" 
> (ACCOUNTID, "CREATED DATE", CASEID) VALUES
>   (1,'2021-07-02',1)
> , (1,'2021-07-03',2)
> , (1,'2021-07-04',3)
> , (2,'2021-07-09',4)
> , (2,'2021-07-09',5)
> , (2,'2021-07-16',5)
> , (3,'2021-07-02',6)
> , (3,'2021-07-09',6)
> , (3,'2021-07-16',6)
>
> CREATE TABLE ACCOUNT (
> ACCOUNTID INT PRIMARY KEY, 
> NAME VARCHAR(30)
> )
>
> INSERT INTO ACCOUNT (ACCOUNTID, NAME) VALUES
> (1,'Mi'),(2,'Maselve'),(3,'Andi')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT *
> FROM
> (
>     SELECT 
>       ACCOUNTID AS "Account ID"
>     , NAME AS "Account Name"
>     , CREATED_WEEK AS "Week"
>     , COUNT(DISTINCT CASEID) AS Tickets
>     FROM
>     (
>       SELECT
>         C.ACCOUNTID
>       , A.NAME
>       , REPLACE(RIGHT(CAST(CAST(DATE_TRUNC('WEEK', C."CREATED DATE") AS DATE)+6 AS VARCHAR(10)), 5),'-','/') AS CREATED_WEEK
>       , CASEID
>       FROM ACCOUNT AS A
>       INNER JOIN "CASE" AS C
>         ON C.ACCOUNTID = A.ACCOUNTID
>       WHERE C."CREATED DATE" >= CAST(DATE_TRUNC('YEAR', CURRENT_DATE) AS DATE)
>         AND EXTRACT('QUARTER' FROM C."CREATED DATE") = 3
>     ) AS Data
>     GROUP BY ACCOUNTID, NAME, CREATED_WEEK
> ) AS Src
> ```

> ```
> Account ID | Account Name | Week  | tickets
> ---------: | :----------- | :---- | ------:
>          1 | Mi           | 07/04 |       3
>          2 | Maselve      | 07/11 |       2
>          2 | Maselve      | 07/18 |       1
>          3 | Andi         | 07/04 |       1
>          3 | Andi         | 07/11 |       1
>          3 | Andi         | 07/18 |       1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=86a68501bde49ea6f39ef71e08f35a8b)*

The extra code for the PIVOT would be something like this

```
PIVOT (
  SUM(Tickets)
  FOR "Week" IN (
        '07/04',
        '07/11',
        '07/18') 
) AS Pvt
```

Comment: @jmizzo  Do you think the calculation for CREATION_WEEK will be much different in [Snowflake](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-date-time.html) ? *(don't have access to one)*